# css image resize messing up only in firefox and IE, works fine in safari and chrome

Tags: html, image, css

So i'm using image css image resizing on a website i've created www.luciaphotography.co.uk , the only problem is that if you hover over the images in FF or IE the text in them looks blurry even though the image's original aspect ratio is 1:1.

Have a look at www.luciaphotography.co.uk and hover over the images (all but the first one as the first image is in the exact size) in chrome or safari, you'll see the text looks fine but try in FF, some look fine some don't and in IE all (except the first) look blurry.

Are there any work arounds without uploading the original image in the exact size?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well know downscaling bug. The downscaling quality of the different browsers vary widely. I don't know of any working workaround..

I think it would be best if you just resize the images beforehand, so that you have a guaranteed outcome quality across all the browser.

It is in general not a good idea to let the browsers do the downscaling. Especially such a huge one like in your case (997px -> 154px).

You could try the [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/image-rendering) property, but I don't think it would improve your outcome as much as you want to.